# How to show dynamic ExpandableViews

Tags: android, expandable

I am fetching a data in my app from server. It is an array with multiple records. There is a `Tablelayout` in which every fetched record is added as a `TableRow`. It works fine. But, now i am using a third party library `ExpandableRelativeLayout` because I want the details appear as one by one and expand only when user clicks it. Following is the `xml` code:

```xml
<!--it calls java function to toggle the below layout-->
<TextView
    android:text="Click to expand +"
    android:onClick="full_test_expand"/>
```

```xml
<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/full_test_expand_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:ael_expanded="false"
    app:ael_duration="500"
    app:ael_orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subject"
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/marks"
            .../>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rank"
            .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

Following is code in java:

```java
ExpandableRelativeLayout full_test_expand_layout;
public void full_test_expand(View v){
    full_test_expand_layout = findViewById(R.id.full_test_expand_layout);
    full_test_expand_layout.toggle();
}
```

This function will do the toggle according to `id`. But, The data is fetched as `array` and loop will be required to fetch and add the record to the view. I want to construct separate `ExpandableView` for each record and construct the same number of views. But, as the expand and collapse is done by using `id`, then it will expand all views by clicking on one as the `id`s will be same. Is there any way that this can be achieved correctly?

Comment: Why don't your try expandablelistview?

Comment: @SumitShukla it will also cause same problem

Comment: Can you show your list structure. Maybe I can help you out.